# Сложение чисел "внутри" переменной

Tags: php

Имеется выражение

```
$a = 5;
$b = + 5;
echo $a . $b;
```

Проблема в том, что необходимо выполнять сложение или вычитание и передавать их внутрь переменной. Проблема в том, что входящее значение может изменяться. Т.е. в один раз будет "+", а в другой будет "-". К статическим выражениям необходимо либо добавлять значения, либо отнимать значения. Заранее спасибо.

Вот собственно и форма:

```
$arr = array(
array(5,5,57.8),
array(5,4,54.6),
array(5,3,51.5),
array(5,2,48.3),
array(5,1,47.8),
array(4,5,53.6),
array(4,4,50.4),
array(4,3,47.3),
array(4,2,44.1),
array(4,1,43.6),
array(3,5,49.4),
array(3,4,46.2),
array(3,3,43.1),
array(3,2,39.9),
array(3,1,39.4),
array(2,5,39.9),
array(2,4,36.8),
array(2,3,36.3),
array(2,2,30.5),
array(2,1,29.9),
array(1,5,15.8),
array(1,4,12.6),
array(1,3,9.5),
array(1,2,6.3),
array(1,1,5.8)
 );

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     foreach($arr as $values)
         {
         if ($values[0] == $_POST['v1'] && $values[1] == $_POST['v2'])
             {
             if (isset($_POST['percent']))
                 {
                var_dump((float)$_POST['percent']);
                 var_dump('Сумма к выдаче: ' . $_POST['inp'] / 100 * ($values[2] . (int)$_POST['percent']));
                 }
               else
                 {
                 echo 'Сумма к выдаче: ' . $_POST['inp'] / 100 * $values[2];
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: $b +=5; $b = $b + 5;

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что вы используете конкатенацию, вместо арифметических операторов, прежде чем писать код ознакомьтесь с документацией.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.arithmetic.php

```
$a = 5;
$a += 5;
echo $a;
```

Comment: Неужели нет идей?